# How to Format Json From Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, ionic-framework

I have problem while parse json which returned by firebase.Here is my JSON

```
{
  "-JxJZRHk8_azx0aG0WDk": {
    "email": "kk@gmail.com",
    "firstname": "dasd",
    "lastname": "sadd",
    "password": "dasdasd"
  }
}
```

I want to access email from Json.
My Controller Code is:

```
var ref = new Firebase('url');
      console.log($scope.user.email);
      ref.orderByChild('email')
        .startAt($scope.user.email)
        //.orderBy('length')
        //.startAt(10)
        .on('value', function(snapshot)
         { 

         console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val(), null, 2));



 }
```

Please Help

Comment: So `snapshot.val().email` isn't working? How about `snapshot.child('email').val()`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this,

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.user1 = {
    "-JxJZRHk8_azx0aG0WDk": {
      "email": "kk@gmail.com",
      "firstname": "dasd",
      "lastname": "sadd",
      "password": "dasdasd"
    }
  };
  $scope.email1 = $scope.user1[Object.keys($scope.user1)[0]].email;
   $scope.user2 = {
    "-dfdhfhdfh": {
      "email": "cdvdvkk@gmail.com",
      "firstname": "dasd",
      "lastname": "sadd",
      "password": "dasdasd"
    }
  };
  $scope.email2 = $scope.user2[Object.keys($scope.user2)[0]].email;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  email Id 1:{{email1}}
  <br>
  email Id 2:{{email2}}
</div>
```

Comment: "-JxJZRHk8_azx0aG0WDk" This will eveytime changed.How to access dynamically email

Comment: With this we can only access static value...How can  get dynamic value.I got error like:  Object.keys called on non-object

Comment: @KaranSofat: Using above method,You can access email that having different keys.Check my updated plunker

Comment: @KaranSofat :Can you give an plunker or fiddle example